# Can I get an element which is deleted from a java collection?

Tags: java, collections

I have a collection and some elements inside it. If I remove one element, then is there any way I can get it back or recover it? Please guide me if it is possible and how.

Comment: When you removed the data from list then store it any temp variable. Or if deleted data are more then one then you can maintain another list to store the deleted data.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I don't have the original collection or a copy of it. Is it possible without having a copy of the collection. This was a question asked in one of the interviews I have appeared recently.

Comment: When you perform the delete operation then you can store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example:

```
List<Object> toRemove = new ArrayList<Object>();
for(Object a: list){
  if(//delete condition){
     toRemove.add(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably this is the answer they were expecting.. Thank you Shiladittya. It was tricky :)

Answer (score 0):

The element will be cleared from the memory by garbage collection as soon as there's no reference to it. This means that you need to keep at least one reference pointing at the actual element to have it alive in the memory. Otherwise consider it gone.

Comment: Thank you... It was helpful... :)

Comment: Welcome. You can mark my answer as the one you looked for, and I'll get 5 points. :-p

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the element before you remove it.  If there is no further reference to the item it may be collected by the garbage collector and there is no way to find it again. To store a reference either set a temporary variable equal to the object before you delete it; or certain collections such as ArrayLists allow you to save the object as you delete it if you use the Remove() method that takes an integer (the index of the element).